# Why does handlebar not appear consistently in the native iOS UI design?

Tags: gui-design, ios, modal-windows, modal-view

Handlebars usually appear at the top of Modal View:
[image: iOS screenshot with a handlebar at the top]

But in other system-level views, there is no handlebar, even if they functionally act like a Modal View. (For instance, this screen, where you can choose devices to send a photo by AirDrop, is definitely a modal task. But the view does not have a handlebar.)

[image: Airdrop screen without handlebar]

Does anyone know the reason for the difference behind these two designs?

Comment: I don't have information to support this idea, but my guess is that swiping down on the top bar of a modal view was not available in all places in the past (the ones that had it previously use the bar), and at some point, that gesture was added as a default system-wide.